# No such table own database android

Tags: android, sqlite

So I want to use my own SQLite database in my Android App. But when I'm trying to get some data I get no such table exception. I have already tried reinstalling App.

Here is *DatabaseHelper* code :

```
package pl.edu.ur.kulturalia;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String databasePath = "/data/data/pl.edu.ur.kulturalia/databases/";
    public static String databaseName = "kulturalia";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, databaseName, null, 1);

    this.myContext = context;
    System.out.println(myContext);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}


public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){

    }else{


        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.getMessage();

        }
    }

}
private boolean checkDataBase() {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {

        String myPath = databasePath + databaseName +".db";

        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {



    }

    if (checkDB != null) {

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    String outFileName = databasePath + databaseName+".db";
    System.out.println(outFileName);

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int i, r;
    AssetManager am = myContext.getAssets();
    String fn = String.format(databaseName);
    InputStream is = am.open(databaseName);
    while ((r = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, r);
    is.close();


    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    System.out.println(myOutput);
}
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {


    String myPath = databasePath + databaseName+".db";
    System.out.println(myPath);
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    System.out.println(myDataBase);
}
public String getKoncert(int id, String tableName) {


    String sql = "Select nazwa from " + tableName + " where _id=?";
    System.out.println(sql);
    System.out.println(myDataBase);
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        cursor.close();
        return name;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return "cos";


    }


}
```

and this is code where I'm using this helper :

```
try {
            db.createDataBase();
            db.openDataBase();
            db.getKoncert(1,"Czwartek");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Just use [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/).

Comment: I want to share my app in market may I use it?